# Apply \@makeschapterhead to TOC and bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, formatting, chapters

I'm writing my thesis and I came up with a custom style for the chapter headings. It works great for chapters with and without an explicit number, but it fails to apply the style to the TOC and bibliography headings.

I found a similar question here: [Apply Chapter heading style to table of contents/bibliography heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177474/apply-chapter-heading-style-to-table-of-contents-bibliography-heading).
However, the solution there seems specific to the problem and I'm not able to apply it to my situation.

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, paper=a4, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,%
          headheight=9pt,%
          margin=2.5cm,%
          bindingoffset=0.5cm,%
          top=3cm,%
          bottom=3cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=phys,%
            biblabel=brackets,%
            pageranges=false,%
            maxbibnames=10,%
            eprint=true,%
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \reset@font
  \vspace*{8\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ 
    \begin{flushright}
      \reset@font \scshape \bfseries {\Huge {\color{blue}\thechapter}} \par
    \end{flushright}
    \begin{flushright}
      \reset@font \uppercase{ \Huge \strut #1\strut \par }
    \end{flushright}
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \reset@font
  \vspace*{8\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ 
    \begin{flushright}
      \reset@font \scshape \bfseries \Huge \vphantom{\thechapter} \par
    \end{flushright}
    \begin{flushright}
      \reset@font \uppercase{\Huge \strut #1\strut\par}
    \end{flushright}
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter*{Abstract}
\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\cite{key}

\backmatter
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Try using `\MakeUppercase` not the primitive `\uppercase` which probably have issues with names stored in macros. Also move the `\par` out of the argument to `\MakeUppercase`. Note that your `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}` will point to the wrong page if the bibliography is longer than a page. `biblatex` probably have tools to automatically add the bibliography to the TOC

Comment: @daleif: Thanks for your reply. Your suggestions made it work. The `\MakeUppercase` command worked, but only after moving `\par` outside of the argument. Also thanks for noting the problem with the bibliography. For those interested: adding `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]` did the trick in `biblatex`.